# NOT IN clause in Sugar ORM

Tags: android, android-database, sugarorm

I have a table `users`. From table `users` I have to select all users excepts some private users. I am storing private users `Id` in `arraylist` and then store into `shared preference`.

Is there any way to use `NOT IN` clause in `query` to fetch all users except some private users.

Answer (score 2):

You can concat the user ids into a string to insert into the "IN" clause. Something like this should work:

```
List<users> users = users.find(users.class, " user_id NOT IN(?)","1,2,3");
```

I would really suggest defining private users by a flag in the table. Then you could do something like this:

```
 List<users> Select.from(users.class).where(!Condition.prop("isPrivate").notEq(true))
```

assuming the object is "users", the flag is "isPrivate" and it could match bool. Basically just insert the correct type to check for into the ".notEq()".